# Php curl multipart/form-data request failed

Tags: php, oracle, php-curl, obiee

I’m under to try getting response from oracle bi publisher using php-curl with header as multipart/form-data but the result it’s **Request failed**

I’m trying also to getting the code from postman directly because it work fine with it but also  result it’s **Request failed**

So please help to fix the code

```
<?php
 
$ch = curl_init();
 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'HOST:PORT/xmlpserver/services/rest/v1/reports/OBTF%2Frapport%2FECHANCE%20LC%2Fapi2/run');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('ReportRequest' => '{\"attributeFormat\":\"html\",\"attributeTemplate\":\"Publisher Template\"}'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'login' . ':' . 'password');
 
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Why do you use Content-Type: multipart/form-data as we don't see any media content being posted

Comment: If HOST and PORT are constants you will have to use string interpolation or `sprintf` to build the endpoint URL

Comment: A multipart request needs to include the _boundary_ value in the Content-Type header. Do not try and set that header yourself - cURL will already do that for you, when an array gets passed for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: @RinsadAhmed multipart/form can file or text and this recommended by oracle

Comment: @CBroe yes i include boundary value and content-length 1 it’s working in postman but php-curl no

Comment: _"yes i include boundary value"_ - where and how? _"and content-length 1"_ - why 1, the data you are sending definitively does _not_ have a length of just 1?

Comment: @CBroe yes please view my answer

Comment: Unless that actually solved your problem, please do not post it as an answer. Edit your question, if you have relevant information to add.

Comment: And I don't think that it _can_ have solved your problem - because it looks like you just added an arbitrary boundary value, but I don't see how that is supposed to have any relation to the one cURL will actually use when it assembles the request body ...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254086/discussion-between-triki-sami-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe

````
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://HOST:PORT/xmlpserver/services/rest/v1/reports/OBTF%2Frapport%2FECHANCE%20LC%2Fapi2/run',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> false,
  CURLOPT_HEADER=> FALSE,
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("ReportRequest"=>'{"attributeFormat":"html","attributeTemplate":"Publisher Template"}'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=--Boundary_4_543972006_1465550732054--','Content-Length:1'
  ),
));```
````